# Wordpress strips my variables when posting a comment

Tags: php, html, wordpress, comments

I'm building a website with pages that are built dynamically. It's not practical for me to build each page and have it as a wordpress page because there will be too many of them, all with the same PHP code that generates content. So I have one page that takes an extra variable through GET request and serves different content based on that.

The URL looks something like this, where page_id is wordpress param for the dynamic page and myParam is my custom parameter that controls what will get pulled from the database to display on the page.

`http://my-website.com/?page_id=112&myParam=7`

It works fine for page rendering, but doesn't work well for the comments section. The problem I get is that after the comment is posted, wordpress returns to the "vanilla" URL `http://my-website.com/?page_id=112` and strips my parameter. As a result, I can't save myParam as comment metadata and after posting a comment, the page jumps to something else, obviously.

Is there any way to make it honor the parameter? I've been trying the whole day to make it work, but everything I tried failed:

- added `query_vars` filter
- changed comments form action to `wp-comments-post.php?myParam=7`
- replaced wp-comments-post.php file from the theme with my own that is supposed to add the param from GET

and few more random attempts and hacks to make it work.

Any help is appreciated. My wordpress skills aren't great, as you can see :) This is probably not the best way to achieve what I need anyways, but I couldn't find any smarter solution.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a few days, but managed to figure out the answer. I'm sure there are better ways to do it, but it works :)

```
// Step 1: inject hidden property with spotId to comments form
function wp_output_comment_params() {

    if (( isset( $_REQUEST['spotId'] )) && ( $_REQUEST['spotId'] != '')) {
        ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="spotId" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['spotId']; ?>">
        <?php
    }     
}
add_action( 'comment_form', 'wp_output_comment_params' );

// Step 2: make sure that we return to the same details page where we posted the comment, so we append argument to the redirect URL
add_filter( 'comment_post_redirect', 'ws_redirect_comments', 10,2 );
function ws_redirect_comments( $location, $commentdata ) {
    if (( isset( $_REQUEST['spotId'] )) && ( $_REQUEST['spotId'] != '')) {
        $location = add_query_arg("spotId", $_REQUEST['spotId'], $location);
    }    
    return $location;
}
```

this should take care of landing page after the comment is posted. Now to add spotId to comment meta-data and to use it to filter comments for display

```
// Step 3: inject metadata from the post, so we can filter by it later
add_action( 'comment_post', 'ws_comment_post' );
function ws_comment_post($comment_id , $comment_approved) {
    if (( isset( $_REQUEST['spotId'] )) && ( $_REQUEST['spotId'] != '')) {
        add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'spotId',  $_REQUEST['spotId'] );
    }
}

// Step 4: filter comments by metadata, so we show only comments for the specified spotId
add_filter( 'comments_template_query_args' , 'ws_filter_comments' , 10, 2 );
function ws_filter_comments( $comment_args ) { 

    if (( isset( $_REQUEST['spotId'] )) && ( $_REQUEST['spotId'] != '')) {
        $comment_args['meta_query'] = [
            [
                'key'     => 'spotId',
                'value'   => $_REQUEST['spotId'],
                'compare' => '='
            ]
        ];        
    }

    return $comment_args;
}
```

Hope that someone dealing with a similar problem might find it useful :)

Cheers